# Displaying a UDF result

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code to remove non European chrs appearing as a unicode and change them to their European equivalent. The formula works but the result is not appearing in the cell. Can you help?

```
Function UniChrLatin(Rg As Range) As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim I As Integer
    xStr = Trim(Rg.Value)
    KeepChrs = Left(xStr, 0)
    For I = 2 To Len(xStr)
        If (Mid(xStr, I, 2)) = "\u" Then
            Readcode = (Mid(xStr, I, 6))
            CorrectUnicode = Replace(Readcode, "\u", "U+")
            NormalLetter = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CorrectUnicode, Worksheets("Unicode").Range("A1:E1000"), 5, False)
            NormalLetter2 = Mid(NormalLetter, 2, 1)
            xStr = KeepChrs & Replace(xStr, (Mid(xStr, I, 6)), LCase(NormalLetter2))
            Debug.Print xStr
            
        Else
            xStr = xStr
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

So the initial ZonguldakK\u00f6m\u00fcrspor

Appears correctly as ZonguldakKomurspor in Debug.print

but in the cell it does not display I'm sure it is a simple tweak.

Comment: Before `End Function`, you need a line:  `UniChrLatin =  xStr` to have that function return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple tweak, just pass the result back through the header:

```
UniChrLatin = xStr
```